# Probability and the expected number with and without replacement from the box

Tags: probability, statistics

In a box, **3** red balls and **4** black balls.

**A** ball is drawn at random **with**
replacement until a red ball is observed.

> With geometric distribution,
> I tried to use it, still cannot find the **expected number** of balls drawn 
> and the **probability** that more than two balls are drawn.

3 balls are drawn at random **without**
replacement until a black ball is drawn.

> With geometric distribution,
> I tried to use it, also still cannot find the **expected number** of black balls drawn

Can anyone solve them? I know it may be an easy question for you, but for the beginner, it is hard to clear the concept.

Comment: ok let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a constant probablity of succeeding on each trail $p$ then the expected number of trails until success is $\frac{1}{p}$. In your first case the probability of pulling a red ball is $\frac{3}{7}$ and so the expected number of pulls until a red is $\frac{7}{3} = 2.333$

In the second case your question is ill defined. It is possible in $3$ draws to still have not seen a black ball so the idea of "3 balls are drawn at random **without** replacement until a black ball is observed." doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean $4$ balls?

Comment: thx for reminding, the second question should be drawn instead of observed